# General solution of wave equation and Helmholtz case

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, wave-equation

In my notes, I found that the following equation

$$\frac{d^2}{d x ^2} \varphi(x) + h \frac{d}{d x} \varphi(x) + k \varphi(x) = 0$$

with $x \in \mathbb{R}$, has the general solution:

$$\varphi(x) = A_1 e^{r_1 x} + A_2 e^{r_2 x}$$

where $r_{1,2}$ are the roots of the characteristic equation

$$r^2 + hr + k = 0$$

1) Is it correct?

2) How is the characteristic equation related to the original equation?

Google results give many different forms of the above equations, with different notations, and the following case is never clearly showed: let's consider $h = 0$, so the [Helmholtz equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HelmholtzDifferentialEquation.html) case, used in Physics as a wave equation:

3) If $k < 0$ and so $r_{1,2}$ are real, what about $C_1$ and $C_2$? And how can their values be determined?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator

specifically to the 'Universal Oscillator Equation' section